# How do I convert date to format "ddmmyyyy"

Tags: r, date

I have a list of date entries where I need to convert every date format to "DDMMYYYY"

Example:

```
a <- c("31 aug 1953", "1953", "aug 1953")
```

Desired output:

```
"31081953", "00001953", "00081953"
```

Comment: a = as.Date(as.date("31 aug 1953"))
format.Date(a,"%d%m%Y"). But it works only for one value how to handle such case when we have list of date value with different pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there are different formats, one option would to `extract` into 'day', 'month', and 'year', then `paste` together after `replace`ing the missing values with 0 formatted with `str_pad`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame(a) %>% 
     extract(a, into = c('day', 'month', 'year'), "(\\d{2})*\\s*([a-z]*)\\s*(\\d{4})") %>% 
     mutate(month = match(toupper(month), toupper(month.abb))) %>% 
     mutate_all(funs(str_pad(replace(., is.na(.), "00"), width = 2, pad = "0"))) %>%
     unite(newcol, day, month, year, sep="") %>%
     pull(newcol)
#[1] "31081953" "00001953" "00081953"
```

Comment: Further addition to analysis: 

request you to please advice how we can achieve below :            example :
entry = c("passport 654133553 expires 11 mar 2019","passport 472420180","passport 563220533 (korea, north)","passport iraq","passport m 788439","following data derived from an eritrean passport issued","passport and national")

desired output :
passport      passport country
"654133553"   NA
"472420180"   NA
"563220533"   "korea, north"
NA            "iraq"
"788439"      NA
NA            NA
NA            NA

Comment: @PNiks  Further addition - please post as a new question

Comment: Tried but stack is given a message not allowed to post more than one question. Request you to please provide your inputs here as i am not allowed to new question. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PNiks  I am not sure why you can't post another question.  People are posting multiple questions

Comment: Don't know why i am getting this error. But it would be very helpful if you can provide your inputs on the same.

Comment: @PNiks  From the comments, it is not clear.  Try `stringr::str_extract(entry, "\\d{5,}")#
[1] "654133553" "472420180" "563220533" NA          "788439"    NA          NA`

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. I have created altogether a new request to for recent question. it can be searched by "Extract|Grep|Substring character vector in R". Request you to please look into this subject line

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into above issue. Please provide assistance

Comment: No above logic is partially correct. Not getting the desired output.

I have created a new question with subject line "Extract|Grep|Substring character vector in R"

Please help.

Comment: @PNiks  Okay, thanks for that.  I already sent a link for you to check.